# Can I use the Advanced Message Queuing Protocol (AMQP)?

Tags: client-server, amqp

We develop system with client-server architecture. But in our case client must communicate with server in *off-line* file mode. Is it correct to use AMQP in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can do that in some cases.  I suggest that you email the rabbitmq-discuss list (you need to subscribe first).  That's a good place to ask questions of this sort!

Hope this helps.

alexis

RabbitMQ

Comment: Can you give me a link to some documentation or discussion of this topic?

Comment: Sasha, try http://www.rabbitmq.com/how.html for general links, or use the search function on rabbitmq.com